# Cocoa app crashes on launch CALayerInvalidGeometry exception

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've encountered this wierd problem which I can't work out how to solve. The problem is that  app is constantly crashing on mac os x 10.9, but on 10.10 it works fine. I am using xcode 6.

App uses *.xib files and there are views that are created programatically.

The crash happens on launch due to **CALayerInvalidGeometry** exception.

The wierd thing is that if 'Show scroll bars' system preference is set to 'When scrolling' or 'Always', app works just fine. 'Automatically based on input device' causes app to crash.

Another observation is that when the app is running and mentioned preferences are switched, (e.g. 'When scrolling' to 'Always') the same exception is thrown, but it does not cause app to crash. But *Invalid rect passed to CoreUI: {{nan,nan},{nan,nan}}* is shown in the output.

I've checked the all the views that are initialized during launch, but I wasn't able to find anything wrong. And there are no direct calls that may provoke the crash according to call stack.

Another observation is that crash occurs when ___NSDetectScrollDevicesThenInvokeOnMainQueue_block_invoke_2 is executed. I wasn't able to find much information about it.

```
2015-05-18 19:26:09.039 MyApp[24355:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'

    *** Call stack at first throw:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x9bcab471 __raiseError + 193
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x995c9091 objc_exception_throw + 162
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x9bcab38b +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
        3   QuartzCore                          0x97319d30 _ZN2CA5Layer12set_positionERKNS_4Vec2IdEEb + 190
        4   QuartzCore                          0x97319c6d -[CALayer setPosition:] + 55
        5   QuartzCore                          0x9731b895 -[CALayer setFrame:] + 807
        6   AppKit                              0x9852dcaf -[NSScrollerImp _updateLayerGeometry] + 293
        7   AppKit                              0x9852dae7 -[NSScrollerImp setKnobProportion:] + 63
        8   AppKit                              0x98687ee1 -[NSScroller setKnobProportion:] + 210
        9   AppKit                              0x98532fa5 -[NSScrollView reflectScrolledClipView:] + 1238
        10  AppKit                              0x9853d944 -[NSClipView _reflectDocumentViewFrameChange] + 157
        11  AppKit                              0x9853d8a0 -[NSClipView _handleFrameChangeForSubview:] + 50
        12  AppKit                              0x98500cac -[NSView _postFrameChangeNotification] + 166
        13  AppKit                              0x9850a28e -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1541
        14  AppKit                              0x986a5a97 -[NSTextView(NSPrivate) _setFrameSize:forceScroll:] + 750
        15  AppKit                              0x986a579e -[NSTextView setFrameSize:] + 63
        16  AppKit                              0x98509c51 -[NSView setFrame:] + 256
        17  AppKit                              0x9858beec -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 949
        18  AppKit                              0x98534d29 -[NSView resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:] + 351
        19  AppKit                              0x9850a18f -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1286
        20  AppKit                              0x9853483b -[NSClipView setFrameSize:] + 407
        21  AppKit                              0x98509c51 -[NSView setFrame:] + 256
        22  AppKit                              0x98537725 -[NSScrollView _setContentViewFrame:] + 591
        23  AppKit                              0x985355d6 -[NSScrollView tile] + 1717
        24  AppKit                              0x98785142 -[NSScrollView setScrollerStyle:] + 481
        25  AppKit                              0x98785214 -[NSScrollView(NSPrivate) scrollerImpPair:updateScrollerStyleForNewRecommendedScrollerStyle:] + 188
        26  AppKit                              0x98ec3e76 +[NSScrollerImpPair _updateAllScrollerImpPairsForNewRecommendedScrollerStyle:] + 407
        27  AppKit                              0x98ec3f70 +[NSScrollerImpPair _scrollerStyleRecommendationChanged:] + 159
        28  Foundation                          0x9bd5d992 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke + 49
        29  CoreFoundation                      0x9bc745a4 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 20
        30  CoreFoundation                      0x9bb5604b _CFXNotificationPost + 3435
        31  Foundation                          0x9bd4c47f -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 92
        32  AppKit                              0x98ec33c9 -[_NSScrollerStyleRecommender setRecommendedScrollerStyleAndNotify:] + 337
        33  AppKit                              0x98ec34b9 __75-[_NSScrollerStyleRecommender scrollerStyleRecommendationUpdateTimerFired:]_block_invoke + 43
        34  AppKit                              0x98eaefcb ___NSDetectScrollDevicesThenInvokeOnMainQueue_block_invoke_2 + 32
        35  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02645800 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
        36  libdispatch.dylib                   0x02641839 _dispatch_client_callout + 50
        37  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0264bff8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 445
        38  CoreFoundation                      0x9bc04fae __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
        39  CoreFoundation                      0x9bbbc3c9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1897
        40  CoreFoundation                      0x9bbbb9ea CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 394
        41  CoreFoundation                      0x9bbbb84b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
        42  HIToolbox                           0x93aefb5d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 259
        43  HIToolbox                           0x93aef8e2 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 526
        44  HIToolbox                           0x93aef6bd _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 92
        45  AppKit                              0x984d1349 _DPSNextEvent + 1602
        46  AppKit                              0x984d0870 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 119
        47  AppKit                              0x984c315c -[NSApplication run] + 727
        48  AppKit                              0x984abff8 NSApplicationMain + 1165
        49  MyApp                             0x00262e0b main + 43
        50  MyApp                             0x00003115 start + 53
    )
```

Comment: Sometimes when weird things like this happen it's worth deleting all caches (i.e. Xcode's and anything created by your app) and if problems persist layout your UI from scratch in a new XIB.